# Unable to detect EUR in a cell of any .xlsx file, using pandas or openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

[image]

I used pandas read_excel, and for these cells got only the numeric values and not the "EUR" (currency).

Then I tried using openpyxl to read the cell values and type I got "int" and not "str".

Using excel editors like Libre calc or MS excel we can convert the currency to the desired output, although, I need to find a way to detect `EUR` as a currency and store the corresponding value in my DB.

Where I am I going wrong? Is there any other way I can detect it?

I have attached the excel sheet here..[Google sheets link..](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11me1RlCL3oAMN6htKoNhyum62hWPJ7E1tuwC3gFLarQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Excel cells can be configured to show "currency" on theire own. Thats just a visual, internally in stores numbers and a "show this cell as currency" meta-info that belongs to the cell. No  EUR to be extracted here ...

Comment: I understand that, can you suggest any package/ param by which i can get this meta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel cells can be configured to show a "currency" on theire own. This is just a visual, internally in stores numbers and a format meta-info that belongs to the cell. You cannot extract EUR from the cells value, but from the format string.

You can query each cell for its the format and parse the `EUR` from it:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(r"stack_excel.xlsx")
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

for n in range(1,10):
    _cell = ws.cell(1,n)              # get a cell
    print((1,n), _cell.number_format) # read the number format of this cell
```

Output:

```
(1, 1) General
(1, 2) General
(1, 3) General
(1, 4) General
(1, 5) General
(1, 6) General
(1, 7) 0
(1, 8) [$EUR]\ 0
(1, 9) [$EUR]\ 0
```